# Mongodb default data in document

Tags: php, mongodb, user-profile

i don't know how to operate for this kind of operation :

I use PHP to access mongodb.

i want to create default data when i have to create an user profil (when the user has registered).

1) I can do a raw insert with a prefilled array each time, i will have a definition with a big array of array with all my defaults values pre-filled.

2) I can have a document which is the default one (ever prefilled) and i would copy this document to another and changing the indexing key (_id).

What is the best way to operate for default data when (for example) an user register on a web site?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally a good way is to use the second method in PHP where by a single class represents a single document in your collection, i.e. you would have a class of `user` which represents a single user in the users collection.

To go further, I would use Active Record.

Within this class you would normally use the classes properties to define a schema and default values for your row and make a function called `save` which will save the properties of the class as a new record.

You can also incorporate your data validation from forms and what not into active record like Yii and Lithium and a few others do.

Active record also provides a basis by which to standardise the querying, retrieval and usage of your data across platforms and databases which is always good.